# On Doubles and Equality

Tags: java, junit, double

One of the methods i have returns a `double`. When testing this method as part of my `jUnit`, i noticed the following oddity:

```
    String a = "someString";
    String b = "someDifferentString";

    double result = c.getScore(a, b, true);
    System.out.println(result); // prints 0.0

    assert (result > 0.0); // Test passes
```

So .. I ask you, how can 0.0 be more then 0.0? Why does `result > 0.0` evaluates to `true`?

Comment: I think you can find the answer in this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285680/representing-monetary-values-in-java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assert is a Java keyword. You need `assertTrue(result > 0.0)`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html as per this documentation, assert Expression is valid, which is want done by OP right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Good catch. I was thinking it might be some floating-point precision problem. +1.

Comment: @thinksteep: from the same page: "By default, assertions are disabled at runtime".

Comment: @JBNizet, ahhh! I should have refreshed my memory before posting the comment, yes, you are correct they are disabled by default. Shouldn't that be answer, enable assert?

Comment: No. This is much too fragile, and what the OP wants is to actually use JUnit to check than the condition is true. An assert is used to verify a postcondition.

Answer (score 7):

Comparing doubles in general is dangerous, because floating-point representations are, by definition, inexact. Furthermore, you have to be careful when printing values out, as the printed representation is often rounded compared to the actual stored representation.

That said, @JBNizet nailed it -- you're writing a Java assertion, not a JUnit test!

Answer (score 7):

It's floating point math that is your worry.  0.0 is probably not absolute 0.0, but 0.00000000000000009 or something really really small.  Why is this?  Well floating point math is discrete in computers.  But in reality floating point math is continuous, and hence we have a mismatch between discrete (digital) and continuous (analog).  Errors begin to creep in causing things to drift a little.  If you want to know more read this:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

There are methods in junit specifically designed for comparing floats/doubles that allow for a tolerance (ie assertEquals(double expected,double actual,double epsilon)).  Use those and you should stabilize your test in the face of the tiny errors you're seeing.  Be aware not to set them too high because your overall error should be very small.

See this question about it as well:

[JUnit assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double epsilon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939788/junit-assertequalsdouble-expected-double-actual-double-epsilon)