# tan() in Java returning a strange value

Tags: java, math

My code passes an angle in radians to the `cos`, `tan` and `sin`. Everything seems to work fine except tan of `90`, which gives the value `16331239353195370` for some odd reason. Example code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class mathtable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Angle   Sin Cos Tan");
    System.out.println("-----   --- --- ---");

    for (double angle = 0.0; angle < 180; angle +=5) {
      double angle_rad = Math.toRadians(angle);
      double sin = Math.sin(angle_rad);
      String sin_4 = new DecimalFormat("#.####").format(sin);
      double cos = Math.cos(angle_rad);
      String cos_4 = new DecimalFormat("#.####").format(cos);
      double tan = Math.tan(angle_rad);
      String tan_4 = new DecimalFormat("#.####").format(tan);
      System.out.println(angle + "  " + sin_4 + "   " + cos_4 + "   " + tan_4);
    }
  }
}
```

Why is the value returned not strictly equal to IEEE infinity?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, `tan(pi/2)` in radians is essentially infinite, isn't it? So you'd expect to get a very large number, wouldn't you? (It's not infinity because pi/2  can't be exactly represented as a `double`. You're finding a value on an asymptotic curve very *close* to where it would become infinite.)

See [these graphs of sin/cos/tan](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/algebra/furthergraphhirev5.shtml) to see what I mean, remembering that pi/2 radians is 90 degrees.

Comment: Not pi/4 but pi/2 = 90 degrees.

Comment: Actually tan(pi/2) is undefined and should return an error. The problem is, pi is not an exact value so tan(pi/2) is very big.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Added the graphs back now. Hopefully they'll stay around... (Another option is just to link to a Google search which shows the graph in the search results of course.)

Comment: I must have missed the meeting when it was decided that all very large values should be represented as the number 16331239353195370 :)

Comment: @jwg: Well don't forget that the input value isn't going to be *exactly* pi/2 radians...

Comment: @JonSkeet yup, it does; thank you for your prompt action, Jon! BTW note that pi/2 has to be *strictly smaller* than actual pi/2 (if it were larger, the result would be negative)

Comment: I had a similar problem when I implemented a quadratic equation solver, and the solution didn't *exactly* solve the original equation (but very close). Also in JUnit the exact double match is deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939788/junit-assertequalsdouble-expected-double-actual-double-epsilon