# Is there special significance to 16331239353195370.0?

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

Using `import numpy as np` I've noticed that

```
np.tan(np.pi/2)
```

gives the number in the title and not `np.inf`

```
16331239353195370.0
```

I'm curious about this number. Is it related to some system machine precision parameter? Could I have calculated it from something? (I'm thinking along the lines of something similar to `sys.float_info`)

**EDIT:** The same result is indeed reproducible  in other environments such as Java, octace, matlab... The suggested dupe does not explain why, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713790/tan-in-java-returning-a-strange-value

Comment: I don't like that answer - it's entirely hand-wavy, not really explaining the cause.  "Well, tan(pi/2) in radians is essentially infinite, isn't it?" doesn't explain anything about why - as the OP asked here - the answer _isn't_ in fact `np.inf`.  But it's straightforward to not only explain why it isn't, but to also explain why the answer is exactly what was seen - and so I did ;-)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`pi` isn't exactly representable as Python float (same as the platform C's `double` type).  The closest representable approximation is used.

Here's the exact approximation in use on my box (probably the same as on your box):

```
>>> import math
>>> (math.pi / 2).as_integer_ratio()
(884279719003555, 562949953421312)
```

To find the tangent of that ratio, I'm going to switch to wxMaxima now:

```
(%i1) fpprec: 32;
(%o1) 32
(%i2) tan(bfloat(884279719003555) / 562949953421312);
(%o2) 1.6331239353195369755967737041529b16
```

So essentially identical to what you got.  The binary approximation to `pi/2` used is a little bit less than the mathematical ("infinite precision") value of `pi/2`.  So you get a very large tangent instead of `infinity`.  The computed `tan()` is appropriate for the actual input!

For exactly the same kinds of reasons, e.g.,

```
>>> math.sin(math.pi)
1.2246467991473532e-16
```

doesn't return 0.  The approximation `math.pi` is a little bit less than `pi`, and the displayed result is correct *given* that truth.

### OTHER WAYS OF SEEING math.pi

There are several ways to see the exact approximation in use:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pi.as_integer_ratio()
(884279719003555, 281474976710656)
```

`math.pi` is exactly equal to the mathematical ("infinite precision") value of that ratio.

Or as an exact float in hex notation:

```
>>> math.pi.hex()
'0x1.921fb54442d18p+1'
```

Or in a way most easily understood by just about everyone:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(math.pi)
Decimal('3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875')
```

While it may not be immediately obvious, every finite binary float is exactly representable as a finite decimal float (the reverse is *not* true; e.g. the decimal `0.1` is not exactly representable as a finite binary float), and the `Decimal(some_float)` constructor produces the exact equivalent.

Here's the true value of `pi` followed by the exact decimal value of `math.pi`, and a caret on the third line points to the first digit where they differ:

```
true    3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510...
math.pi 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
                         ^
```

`math.pi` is the same across "almost all" boxes now, because almost all boxes now use the same binary floating-point format (IEEE 754 double precision).  You can use any of the ways above to confirm that on *your* box, or to find the precise approximation in use if your box is an exception.

Comment: @Tim Peters - This is perfectly clear. For completeness I'm guessing that this representation of `np.pi` is the closest rational representation to within system's epsilon?

Comment: Assuming `np.pi` has the same value as Python's `math.pi` (I didn't check, but you can ;-) ), it's the closest value to the mathematical pi representable in the platform's native `C double` floating-point format.  Which means IEEE 754 double-precision on almost all boxes now, and so the closest binary float with 53 bits of (mantissa) precision.  So the set of rationals is constrained to the form `+/- I * 2**J` where integer `I` is 0 or `2**52 <= I < 2**53`, and the range of integer `J` is way broad enough to cover all rationals of this form anywhere near `pi`.

Comment: And this is why I'd _love_ if "binary" trigonometric functions were more commonly implemented. Since pi can never be represented in a rational, it would be handy with a set of functions operating on angles from 0 to 1.

Comment: Well, they imported `np.pi`, not `math.pi`.

Comment: @Έρικ Κωνσταντόπουλος `math.pi`, `np.pi`, and `scipy.pi` are all the same; they're duplicated just for naming convenience; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645547/should-i-use-scipy-pi-numpy-pi-or-math-pi