# Java Junit Failed: The test case is a prototype bug?

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

```
package Jut;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class JUTest {


@Test  
public void testDoubleComparison() {  

    double expected = 10.20;  
    double actual = 10.20;  

    assertEquals(expected, actual, 0.0);  
}  

}
```

Test Run says: No test passed, 1 test failed: The test case is a prototype. (junit.framework.AssertionFailedError)

But I'm sure this will works fine. Why it doesn't passed? I'm using Netbeans and the newest Junit (I think 4.10?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"assertEquals" fails because the values are double

You can try using some value > 0 for epsilon

```
assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double epsilon)
```

So that will assert to true as long as `Math.abs(expected - actual) < epsilon`

Comment: can you try a smaller value like 0.01 for eplison

Comment: Similar question has been asked previously in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939788/junit-assertequalsdouble-expected-double-actual-double-epsilon. As stated in it, eplison describes how close you need the double values to be.

Comment: it gives me the same failure message (prototype)... assertEquals(10.24, 10.24, 0.01)...

Comment: int expected = 10;  
int actual = 10;  
assertEquals(expected, actual); doesen't work, too.

Comment: So on: assertEquals(12, 12); gives me the test case is a prototype? I think long values are valid in Junit 4.10.

Comment: Can you paste the failure message

Answer (score 0):

```
public void testComprovaNumero() {
    System.out.println("comprovaNumero");
    double num = 0.0;
    checknum instance = new checknum();
    double expResult = 0.0;
    double result = instance.comprovaNumero(num);
    assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
    // fail("The test case is a prototype."); ----> Commenting on this line of code is what made the problem disappear

}
```

I hope it works for someone!

Answer (score -1):

Nothing's wrong with your test. I've tried with JUnit 4.12 and Netbeans IDE 8.2 and test passes. I also think it's a bug.