# Why does my JUnit test for this set of codes always return errors?

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to write the Junit test code for the following code:

```
public class RateofPay {

   public double totalSalary(double work, double work2, double hour1, double hour2, double hour3) {

    double salary1 = work * hour1;
    double salary2 = work2 * hour2;
    double salary3 = work * hour3;
    double wages = salary1 + salary2 + salary3;
    return wages;
    }
  }
```

And this is the JUnit test I have wrote:

```
public class WageTest {

@Test
public void testWage() {
    RateofPay test=new RateofPay();
    double result=test.totalSalary(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0);
    assertEquals(12.0, result);

}

@Test
public void testWage1() {
    RateofPay test=new RateofPay();
    double result=test.totalSalary(6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0);
    assertEquals(157.0, result);

 }
}
```

The problem is that every time when I run the JUnit test, none of them pass the test. The result says

> assertEquals(expected, actual, delta) to compare floating point number.

I'm wondering what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please share the failure logs.

Comment: Looks like math is wrong! it should be 16 and 171!

Comment: more details regarding the delta are available on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939788/junit-assertequalsdouble-expected-double-actual-double-epsilon

Comment: Hint: the **real** solution here is: do some research on your error message. You already had **all** the information you need at hand. When JUnit tells you "please do X"; then heck: go and google what "X" is about. In essence, your problem is that you do not understand how computers deal with floating point numbers; and thus you do not understand how to write code dealing with floating point numbers. So: simply step back, turn to the books and **learn** about "computers & floating point numbers". You can start reading the "duplicated" question I put up; esp. response 3 by madma is for you ...

Answer (score 4):

You should specify the `delta` parameter when trying to compare `double` numbers.
Besides, your assertions are wrong.

They should be like this.

```
    @Test
    public void testWage() {
        Solution test=new Solution();
        double result=test.totalSalary(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0);
        assertEquals(16.0, result, 0.0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWage1() {
        Solution test=new Solution();
        double result=test.totalSalary(6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0);
        assertEquals(171.0, result, 0.0);

    }
```

For example, the first test would have this calculation:

```
double salary1 = 1 * 3; //3
double salary2 = 2 * 4; //8
double salary3 = 1 * 5; //5
double wages = salary1 + salary2 + salary3; // 3 + 8 + 5 = 16
```

Comment: You could have mentioned at least in a half-sentence *why* one needs to use some *epsilon* when comparing floating point numbers in general.