# Is it ok to use assertTrue on float and double values in JUnit?

Tags: junit, decimal, assert

I tried using the assertEquals method on a float and eclipse says that the method was depreciated. Therefore, is the following alternative acceptable?

```
Assert.assertTrue("Total does not match expected total :",
                                            receipt.getTotal() == 32.19f);
```

Is there a specific reason why assertEquals must not be used to compare two floats or doubles in a test?

In general, what is the best way to assert the equality of two decimal values in JUnit. I am using the 4.10 release of JUnit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you can compare primitive types with ==, but with floating point values, two values can look the same (when formatted as a string) but be two different values. You should be using [assertEquals(expected, actual, delta)](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double,%20double%29). See the answer to [JUnit: assertEquals for double values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686755/junit-assertequals-for-double-values).

Because double (and float) calculations are not necessarily exact, you can compare using a delta (effectively a margin of error).