# JUnit: allow 1 second difference between expected and actual

Tags: java, unit-testing, time, junit, rounding

I am developping something which keeps the current age of the oldest item, for code coverage I write JUnit tests.

So when I write my unit tests, I perform following action:

```
currentAge = resultSet.getTime(4);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Assert.assertEquals(new Time(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - 1,cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) - 30,Calendar.SECOND), currentAge);
```

This actualy works, but I get sometimes this test failure

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
>   Expected :08:09:14
>
> Actual  :08:09:13

I think the reason is that the sequence of the actions maybe makes sometimes 1 second difference. Is there any way to round this in a good way or making the test to perform that 1 second difference is allowed?

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the delta argument to your assertEquals method - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686755/meaning-of-epsilon-argument-of-assertequals-for-double-values) and [this javadoc](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html)

Comment: can you give me of an example with a delta with 1 second, used in java.sql.time object?

Comment: What type is your currentAge variable? I'd suggest using cal.getTimeinMillis() to get a long number, doing the same for your currentAge variable and then comparing using assertEquals with 1000L as your delta value (1000 milliseconds = 1 second)

Comment: ok good answer. My currentAge is a java.sql.time, which contains a long method getTime() to get the milis. :-)