# How do I do Inverse tan of a Gradian?

Tags: java

I have the gradian of 5. When I do inverse tan, I get the answer 0.007. The actual answer is 87.43. What formula do I use to get the right answer?

I did:

```
textDoub = textDoub / 1.11111111111;
textDoub = Math.atan(Math.toRadians(textDoub));
```

`textDoub` is the amount of grad.

Comment: Are you sure you have a *gradian*?  It looks like you're doing operations on *radians*.

Comment: You shoul go to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @xsami:  Not necessarily.  It's too unclear to say for certain.

Comment: So then the division operation on `textDoub` converts it over to a radian, then?  Bear in mind that `Math#toRadians` is only considering the radian value of whatever you're passing in.

Comment: I get a random number to textDoub

Comment: i want it to show me tan inverse in gradians. I am working on a calculator right now

Comment: Plugging your [math into Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=atan%28degrees+to+radians%285%2F%2810%2F9%29%29%29) gives neither `0.0007` nor `87.43`.  Please update your question with the actual mathematical equation (including units) you're trying to implement in Java.  As is, we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: Inverse tan of 5 grad IS 87.43.

Comment: @dimo414 `atan()` takes a slope and returns an angle.  It's the angle that needs converting.  Not the slope.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I simply took what OP posted and put it into Google.  If the result of that transcription is incorrect or ambiguous, that's the point I was trying to make.  If OP posts a Google/Wolfram-Alpha/etc. link showing exactly the calculation they're trying to implement in Java it will make the question much clearer, and more clearly on-topic for StackOverflow.  As is, I assume the downvotes are due to this ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

> The [gradian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian) is a unit of plane angle, equivalent to 1⁄400 of a turn. It is also known as gon, grad, or grade. One grad equals 9⁄10 of a degree or π⁄200 of a radian.

A gradian is an angle.  Whether in degrees, radians, or gradians, inv tan takes a slope and returns an angle.  Doing an inv tan of a gradian doesn't make sense.

```
gradians = 200 / Math.PI * Math.atan(slope)
```

If you're going to be working with gradians much, having conversion methods might be handy.

```
double gradianToRadian(double gradian) {
    return gradians * Math.PI / 200;
}

double radianToGradian(double radian) {
    return radians / Math.PI * 200;
}
```

Putting that together gives:

```
gradians = radianToGradian( Math.atan(slope) )
```

[Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686755/meaning-of-epsilon-argument-of-assertequals-for-double-values) your example problem:

```
assertEquals(87.43, radianToGradian( Math.atan(5) ), 0.001);

assertEquals(gradianToRadian(87.43), Math.atan(5), 0.001);

assertEquals(Math.tan( gradianToRadian(87.43) ), 5, 0.001);
```

I think the numbers you gave are correct.  Just mislabeled.  5 is a slope not a gradian.  87.43 is the gradian.

Gradians are angles.  You don't do an "inverse tan of a gradian".  You convert to gradian after doing an inverse tan on a slope.

Comment: Doesn't return the needed value.

Comment: atan should return a radian value rather than accept one.  Should the conversion be done on the functions result?

Comment: In a calculator, there is deg, rad, and grad. I make it mode grad and enter inverse tan of 5. I get the answer 87.43. In my program, i try to do the same. It;s in grad mode and I receive a number, example, 5. I don't understand what to do next to get the right answer, 87.43

Comment: @Compsci 5 is not the gradian here.  87.43 is the gradian.  Gradians are angles.  Angles are what come out of inv tan.  Slopes are what go into inv tan.